# App crashes, WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, web, android-webview

the app doesn't work I don't know what am I doing wrong please help me, there is code
MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String url = "https://www.webnotes.cz/";
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient (new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            String user="u";
            String pwd="p";
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('UID0').value = '"+user+"';document.getElementById('PASS0').value='"+pwd+"';");
        }
    });
}
```

}

Thanks for your respond guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Android app crashes for initializing variable with findViewById(R.id.\*\*\*\*\*\*) at the beginning of the class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446114/why-android-app-crashes-for-initializing-variable-with-findviewbyidr-id)

Comment: When you want help debugging a crash, you need to include the details of the crash, including when it happens, what actions cause it, and the stack trace generated in your logcat.

Comment: I guess `mWebView` is null and your are getting a NPE

Comment: Post the error log first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:- Initialize webview or any other view in onCreate method only... Because findviewById will not get id of that view before setting content view(layout)**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final WebView mWebView;
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Views should be initialized after inflating the view to activity, which is done using setContentView(). Move below line to onCreate() method after setContentView();

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```