# android hiding ui and showing ui code not working

Tags: android, user-interface

```
package com.example.eiraj.listviewseefrgmentsfiirst;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    public void show(View view){
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hide(View view){
       textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
}
```

here two buttons are being used to show data and hide data but whenever I try to run it emulator shows the message *unfortunately uihide stopped* also I downloaded the apk to run it on my phone but same message came there

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446114/why-android-app-crashes-for-initializing-variable-with-findviewbyidr-id

Answer (score 1):

Move `TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);` inside `onCreate`
while keeping `textView` reference outside `onCreate` because before the execution of `onCreate` there is no layout attached to your activity , hence the issue

```
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
```

---

Then your `MainActivity.java` will be

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;

    public void show(View view){
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hide(View view){
       textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

}
```

Plus you can also use `textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` if you want to completely make your view invisible

Answer (score 0):

Attach your `TextView` inside `onCreate()`:

```
package com.example.eiraj.listviewseefrgmentsfiirst;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);        
    }       

    public void show(View view){
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hide(View view){
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't initialize Views before `setContentView()` is called and it is compulsory to call `setContentView()` inside `onCreate()` method.

Do like this:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
```